# How do I reload/Refresh a W3IFrameHtmlElement in Smart Mobile Studio?

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

How do I reload/Refresh a W3IFrameHtmlElement in Smart Mobile Studio?

Version 2.2

When I assign the source property the first time, it works great. When I assign it the second or subsequent times, it never works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
W3IFrameHtmlElement1.Handle.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

which access the underlying DOM element directly. With this approach everything beyond the Handle needs to be case sensitive

If you want to have type safety in your code (plus case insensitivity) you can also typecast the variant handle to the dedicated W3C specified class like this:

```
JHTMLIFrameElement(W3IFrameHTMLElement1.Handle).contentWindow.location.reload;
```

Note that you need to use the unit W3C.HTML5 for this:

```
uses W3C.HTML5;
```